# Javascript need to take info from text boxes and use them for functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tax Calculator</title>
    <!-- Name: Jacob Zoppina-->
    <!--Section: 25-->
    <!--TA: Fang Wang-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Payroll Processing</h1>
    <h2>Report Generator</h2>
    <hr>
    <style>
        h1 {
            text-align: center; background-color: black; color: darkgreen;
        }
        h2 {
            text-align: center; background-color: lightgreen; color: black;
        }
        body {
            background: lightyellow
        }
    </style>
    <p> Department: <input name="department" type="text" id="dpt" value=""/></p>
    <hr>

    <p>Employee 1: <input name="empId" type="text" id="initials1" value=""/>
        <input name="hoursWorked" type="text" id="work1" value=""/>
        <input name="hourlySalary" type="text" id="salary1" value=""/>
    </p>
    <p>Employee 2: <input name="empId" type="text" id="initials2" value=""/>
        <input name="hoursWorked" type="text" id="work2" value=""/>
        <input name="hourlySalary" type="text" id="salary2" value=""/>
    </p>
    <p>Employee 3: <input name="empId" type="text" id="initials3" value=""/>
        <input name="hoursWorked" type="text" id="work3" value=""/>
        <input name="hourlySalary" type="text" id="salary3" value=""/>
    </p>
    <hr>
    <p><input type="button" value="Process" onclick="myFunction()"/>
        <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="clears();"/>
    </p>
    <script>
    function departmentName() {document.getElementById("dpt")
                               document.write("Department Name:"+departmentName)
                              }
    function totalHours (var wrk1, wrk2, wrk3;) {}
    </script>
</body>
```

`I am an absolute javascript beginner and I am only doing it for a college course. I am struggling on my final javascript assignment and I cannot figure it out. I'm not asking for someone to do my homework for me I just need somewhere to start. You will use a text box to get the department’s name. I have to use text boxes to get Employee ID his/her initials), Hours worked during the week and Hourly salary. Each department may have up to 3 employees.A button will generate a report, which will display on a separate page, including, The name of the department. The Regular Salary and Overtime salary for each employee, a summary section with, Department Regular Hours, Department Overtime Hours, Total Department Regular Salaries, Total Department Overtime Salaries, Total Department Salaries.
Another button to clear previous entries and reset memory variables, I have to use at least one function for the salaries calculations.
I have to use a loop, in conjunction with an array, for the salaries calculations. The report will be produced using the Dynamic Web page creation techniques using document.write statements).

What I really need is just somewhere to start, I don't want someone to do my homework I kinda just need an example of how to get data from a text box, put it in an array somehow, and then use document.write to display the final product. For example I need to figure out how to take the data from my text boxes labeled "hours worked" and have them add up together and then display itself on a separate page. I feel like if I can learn how to do just one section of the boxes then I can replicate it onto my other groups of boxes.

Comment: I can show my basic code, or explain this some more, I really just need somewhere to start or an example of how to do something like this. I am a business major being forced to take a coding class and I just want to pass. I have looked all through my textbook and I am so lost.

Comment: Show your code..

Comment: Post that code into your question. Nobody will look at this like that. Then where is your JS code?

Comment: I posted it, the JS is jibberish

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript gives us some selectors by which we can get perticular element and its value these are below: 
**1. Id Selector:** By which we can get element by its unique id.
         ex:`document.getElementById('#id')`

**2. Element Name Selector:** By actual element we can get data.
ex:`document.getElementByName('nameOfElement')`

**3. Class Selector:** By the class also we can element values
ex:`document.getElementByClass('className')`

But in your case, as you have several input fields for different purpose
you can use **Id Selector** to get perticular element values.

example:

**HTML:**

```
<form name="userForm">
   <input type='text' id="name">
   <input type='password' id="password">
   <button type='submit' onClick="submit()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function submit(){
 var userName=document.getElementById('name').value();
 var password=document.getElementById('password').value();
 // now you can make your micro-service call
}
```